# Using Fourier series to prove $-\int_0^1 u_{xxx}u_x \eta = \int_0^1 (u_{xx})^2\eta - \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} (u_x)^2 \eta_{xx}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $u, \eta$ be smooth functions and $\eta$ compactly supported in $(0,1)$. Integrating by parts, we can easily prove $$-\int_0^1 u_{xxx}u_x \eta = \int_0^1 (u_{xx})^2\eta - \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} (u_x)^2 \eta_{xx}$$

Can we obtain the same result using only the Fourier series
$$u(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt 2 \cos (\pi n x) \, a_n, \qquad \eta(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt 2 \cos (\pi n x) \, b_n $$
as a tool?

Comment: without partial integration, you can just evaluate all integrals and the result will follow, but it will be a tedious calculation; any motivation for avoiding P.I. ?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I want to study a similar identity for a more general operator, where the Fourier expansion is all I have, but then I realized that I'm not even able to compute the integrals in the case of the Laplacian. How would you evaluate them?

Comment: see answer box, quite a tedious calculation, but it works out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

term on left hand side:
$$L=-\int_0^1 dx\, u_{xxx}u_x \eta =2^{3/2}\pi^4 \sum_{n,m,k=1}^\infty n^3m a_na_mb_k \int_0^1 dx\,\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi x)\cos(k\pi x)=$$
$$=2^{3/2}\pi^4 \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n,m,k=1}^\infty n^3m a_na_mb_k \left(\delta_{m,n+k}+\delta_{n,m+k}-\delta_{k,n+m}\right).$$
two terms on right hand side
$$R_1=\int_0^1 dx\, u_{xx}^2 \eta =2^{3/2}\pi^4 \sum_{n,m,k=1}^\infty n^2m^2 a_na_mb_k \int_0^1 dx\,\cos(n\pi x)\cos(m\pi x)\cos(k\pi x)=$$
$$=2^{3/2}\pi^4 \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n,m,k=1}^\infty n^2m^2 a_na_mb_k \left(\delta_{m,n+k}+\delta_{n,m+k}+\delta_{k,n+m}\right).$$
$$R_2=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 dx\, u_{x}^2 \eta_{xx} =\frac{1}{2}2^{3/2}\pi^4 \sum_{n,m,k=1}^\infty nmk^2 a_na_mb_k \int_0^1 dx\,\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi x)\cos(k\pi x)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}2^{3/2}\pi^4 \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n,m,k=1}^\infty nmk^2 a_na_mb_k \left(\delta_{m,n+k}+\delta_{n,m+k}-\delta_{k,n+m}\right).$$
left hand side minus right hand side
$$L-R_1-R_2=2^{3/2}\pi^4 \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=n+1}^\infty (mn^3-nm^3)a_na_m b_{m-n}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty (mn^3-nm^3)a_{n}a_m b_{n-m}\right.$$
$$\left.+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n,m=1}^\infty m n (m^2 -n^2)a_na_m b_{n+m}\right)=0.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Please, let me know if you manage to solve the right-hand side

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you add some details to the last line? Why is $L-R_1-R_2 \equiv 0$?

Comment: Also in that line, why is $k$ gone?

Comment: the double sum over $n,m$ vanishes by symmetry, exchanging $n$ and $m$; I have used the Kronecker delta to carry out the sum over $k$.

Comment: Thanks! Among the factors $(mn^3-nm^3), \quad  (mn^3-nm^3), \quad m n (m^2 -n^2)$, where did the contribution of $k$ end up?

Comment: $k=m-n$ or $k=n-m$ gives the factor $-m^2 n^2+m n^3-\frac{1}{2} m n (m-n)^2=(1/2)(mn^3-nm^3)$; $k=m+n$ gives the factor $-m^2 n^2-m n^3+\frac{1}{2} m n (m+n)^2=(1/2)mn(m^2-n^2)$

Comment: I was looking again at the computations: what do you mean by "symmetry"? Does it imply that each of the series is zero or is the sum of the three series zero?

Comment: symmetry means this: consider the second sum and rename $m\leftrightarrow n$; then you get the first sum with the opposite sign, so these two sums cancel; now consider the third sum and again rename $m\leftrightarrow n$; then you get the same sum with the opposite sign, so it must be equal to zero.

Comment: Thank you so much. If one wants to modify the identity a bit and consider $$L=2^{3/2}\pi^4 \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n,m,k=1}^\infty n^{2}m a_na_mb_k \left(\delta_{m,n+k}+\delta_{n,m+k}-\delta_{k,n+m}\right).$$
$$R_1=2^{3/2}\pi^4 \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n,m,k=1}^\infty n^{3/2}m^{3/2} a_na_mb_k \left(\delta_{m,n+k}+\delta_{n,m+k}+\delta_{k,n+m}\right).$$
$$R_2=\frac{1}{2}2^{3/2}\pi^4 \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n,m,k=1}^\infty n^{1/2}m^{1/2}k^2 a_na_mb_k \left(\delta_{m,n+k}+\delta_{n,m+k}-\delta_{k,n+m}\right).$$
Would $L-R_1-R_2$ still be zero? (More general: what exponents of $m,n,k$ would work?)

Comment: no that will not work; different exponents in the different terms will mess things up.

Comment: Thanks. This has inspired another question (where the change should have something to do with the change in the exponents): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382312/prove-integration-by-parts-formula-for-spectral-fractional-laplacian

Comment: I have also opened another question on MathStackexchange, precisely about computing the example in the comments: even if not zero, I'd like to be able to compute what it is exactly: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4002492/compute-the-difference-of-three-series-motivated-by-an-integral-formula